# Declare object type in class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object, ecmascript-6

I should create a js class respecting a json format

```
{
  "rows": [{
    "value": {
        "comments": ${dInfo.description},
        "Tags": [],
        "metadataList": {
          "names": [],
          "metadata": {}
         },
  }]
}
```

I would like to know how to declare `metadata`.

I'm declaring like this actually.

```
export class Value {
  comments: string;
  Tags:string[];
  metadataList:{
    name:string[],
    metadata: Object
  }
}
```

Here `metadataList` is not typed which is not a best practice I think.
how could I declare `metadataList` with it's type ?

Comment: Why do you think so? Object is typed.

Comment: I'm not sure but when I'm trying `metadataList: Object{..}` It's not working , is only `{}` make it typed ?

Comment: provide  an example or Fenton answer should help.

Comment: Since you already have to come up with `class Value { ... }` what holds you back from implementing your own `class MetadataList { ... }` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If metadata is a key/value store, you can make the type a little narrower than `Object` or `{}` by tightening up the value types:

```
class Value {
  comments: string;
  Tags:string[];
  metadataList:{
    name:string[],
    metadata: { [key: string]: string }
  }
}

const val = new Value();

val.metadataList = {
    name: ['Example'],
    metadata: {
        key: 'value',
        key2: 'value'
    }
};
```

If you have more information about your metadata, I may be able to make it even narrower.

Comment: So you have some sample data? i.e. what will be in metadatalist - in particular what is different to my example?

Comment: Should I specify metadataList type `Object{..}` rather than only `{..}` ?